# How to access minorgrid property and build fine grid by changing line type and color in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to implement a minor grid and I would to do it, as well as change the minorgrid line type and thickness. This is much easier to do in `Python`, and you can easily call any property with plt.plot. How to implement similar in Julia?

```
using Plots
f(x) = sqrt(x);
c = 2;
fp = SymPy.diff(f(x), x);       # diff finds derivative, fp an expression (not function)
m = fp(x=>c)            # at c=2
p =plot(f(x), 1, 3, 
    linealpha = 0.5,
    linewidth = 4,
    linecolor = :red,
    xticks = 0:0.4:10, 
    yticks = 0:0.4:10
    )
pp = plot!(f(c) + m * (x - c),
    linewidth = 4,
    linecolor = :blue)
xgrid!(pp, :on, :grey, 1, :dashdot, 0.7)
ygrid!(pp, :on, :grey, 1, :dashdot, 0.7)
```